# asp.net mvc DropDownListFor Not populating

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I think I am missing something here. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. In my view I have a drop down list that is being tied to my model. Straightforward stuff.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GaragingAddress.State, 
                      POSBridge.Helpers.StateAbbreviations(), 
                      new {id="ADStreetState"})
```

The helper function I reference is here (its not the most efficient, but right now I am concentrating on proof of function and not performance.)

```
namespace POSBridge
{
    public class Helpers
    {
        public static List<SelectListItem> StateAbbreviations(bool includeTerritories = false)
        {
            List<string> abbreviations = new List<string>
            {
                "",
                "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
                "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD",
                "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"
            };
            if (includeTerritories)
            {
                abbreviations.AddRange(new string[] { "AS", "GU", "MP", "PR", "VI", "UM" });
            }

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (string s in abbreviations) items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s, Value = s });
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

When the page renders, the select list with the state is not being populated. All the state values appear in the drop down list. Other drop down lists on the page are getting populated without error, and when I place a breakpoint here and check the model values in the immediate window, the Model.GaragingAddress.State property certainly has a value. Therefore, I am sure it probably has something to do with the Helper function I wrote, but I am not sure what/how.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was odd and unexpected, but the following code worked.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GaragingAddress, 
    new SelectList(POSBridge.Helpers.StateAbbreviations(), 
                   "Value",
                   "Text", 
                   Model.GaragingAddress.State), 
    new { id="ADStreetState" })
```

I have no idea why this works and the other doesn't but who am I to complain if something is working?